# Integration over measurable space

Tags: measure-theory

I am working on measure theory and I am having a bit of a confusion.If we let $(\mathbb{X},\alpha,\mu)$ be our measurable space. I know the definition of integration for a simple function $f^\ast$ is
$$\int f^\ast d\mu=\sum a_i \mu (E_i)$$
A question arises here, is that as integration over ALL over $\mathbb{X}$? how would one limit this to a subset? Define the sub-measure space? That is what makes me uncertain, especially when one extends this to a measurable function with the convergent sequence $\{f^\ast_n\}$ to our integrable function $f$, i feel making the subset measurespace is the right action to do but I am not sure.

Comment: There is no essential need to limit to a (measurable) subset. If you want to "work over $A$" instead over $\mathbb X$ then multiply every function involved with $1_A$, realizing that $\int_Afd\mu=\int f1_Ad\mu$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to integrate over $A\in\alpha$, then

$$\int_A f^*d\mu=\sum a_i\mu(E_i\cap A)$$

And this is exactly what you'd get if you considered the sub-measure space $(A,\alpha_A,\mu_A)$ since $\alpha_A$ is defined as the intersections of $A$ with the elements of $\alpha$.

By the way, some authors directly define the integral of a simple function on a subset of $\mathbb{X}$, and they do it like this.

Comment: I had such a feeling as they would be equivalent, I just wanted to make certain my idea was correct